# how to set the class col-sm for a div on http.get() method success

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this html page where i havce included 4 templates and menu for each is given as tabs on top.
I want to change the width of tab(div) in col-sm- 4 to lets say col-sm-6 when an http.get() method returns true i.e success

here is the html menu code..

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-success" ng-click="go('/AddBook')">
            <h2>Add a Book</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-info" ng-click="go('/SearchBook')">
            <h2>Search a Book</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-success"
            ng-click="getAllBooks(); go('/ViewAllBooks')">
            <h2>View All Books</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 bg-info" ng-click="go('/RequestBook')">
            <h2>Request a Book</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the snapshot of the html page ....
[image]

now when an http.get() method succeeds , i want to change the width of searchbook, request book and view all books to change..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the $http documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

In **[config]** you can pass success and error functions.

Much like this:

```
get(url, 
    function(data){ 
       $scope.getSuccessful = true; 
    }, 
    function(errorData){
        $scope.getSuccessful = false;
    }
);
```

After the call, success/error should be called. Then set the value of the class in html.

```
<div class="{{getSuccessful ? 'col-md-2' : 'col-md-10'}}" ng-click="go('/RequestBook')">
    <h2>Request a Book</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try something like.

```
ng-class="{ 'col-md-6' : expression }"
```

Check the docs for this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

Put promises on http.get() and on success assign a true value to a scoped variable and then in the Ui use ng-class as stated by adeel_s